# Can I install a custom recovery and the Xposed Framework from the recovery in Samsung galaxy C7 pro?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, twrp, xposed-framework

No one can deny that one of the greatest advantage of having a rooted device is having the Xposed Framework running under the hood. But that needs rooting my device. I'm unwilling to do that as it's my dad's new phone and is less than 6 months old. I've recently hypothesized a way to install the framework without rooting the device. But I cannot test it as I mentioned the phone is damn new, so an advice is welcome.

In the android recovery there is an option to apply update from sd card. I think I can flash the image file of the custom recovery TWRP from the recovery. After I'm done and things go the right way I can flash the Xposed installer .zip file from TWRP and then will get Xposed working fine.

**Note**

The Xposed Framework after installation behaves as a system app and can work fine without root access, it only needs the root access while installation of the .zip file.

It would be a great help if anyone can help me. Please guide me through the process so that I can have the Xposed Framework w/o rooting my phone.

Comment: Ever tried [Magisk](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk)? It's "systemless root" with "systemless Xposed", and even "root hiding" and more. Check [this thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/official-magisk-v7-universal-systemless-t3473445) for the most recent version and installation instructions.

Comment: "I think I can flash the image file of the custom recovery TWRP from the recovery." Sorry, nope, since it's only meant to accept stuff signed by the manufacturer.

Comment: By the way, certain Samsung phones (such as the Galaxy A5, 2017 model) detect `boot.img` tampering, so systemless root is out of the equation. I've smashed against the "feature" myself.

Comment: @AndyYan so u say no hopes here. Btw thanks.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman please elaborate. What are the risks for trying out systemless root. Thank you.

Comment: @Izzy Can u inform me more about systemless root. I'm the noob here.

Comment: Not in the comments. But check [these posts](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=systemless+root) for some background. If that leaves open questions, ask them separately :) Best post to start with: "What is [systemless root](/q/132753/16575)?"